# How to save HTML div or table data into PDF at desired location using JavaScript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

How to save HTML div or table data into PDF at desired location using JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: why don't you google it first before asking it here?

Answer (score 0):

This ([Php : create pdf from html using mpdf](http://www.binarytides.com/create-pdf-from-html-using-mpdf-in-php/)) tells about [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/), which is an PHP Library that parses HTML/CSS to generate PDF files.

Comment: I had googled but end up with nothing. 

What I exactly want is like something else.  I have created a web page which includes php codes and javascript to plot charts and pictures. Most of them are in div or in tables. 

A member user  have permission to generate such charts and reports. They can generate the report and view it instantly in current webpage however for some reasons, non-members are not allowed to do so. Instead they can view the generated report.

Comment: So wondering if I can save each of the div or table into separate pdf file into the database and from there non-member user will use to view the files. I will have some buttons  in each section from where when member user wish to save the generated report for other user's view, he may use the button to do so. Many thanks.